# How to Implement Mongoid callbacks in a Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to implement a model auditor that looks for changes to the Mongo.  Originally, I tried to make a base class that my models inherit from, but I found out that's [not possible](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133).

I'm adding a module to a model that relies on Mongoid.  The module contains after_create, after_update, and after_destroy callbacks.  And that's the problem...  In order to get the callbacks to work as if they are class-level methods, I have to do something this.

```
module Auditor
  def self.after_create
    #after create code
  end
end
```

However, I this will override any after create calls inside my model.

Is there a way I can modify my Auditor module's after_create method to accept what the model wants to run callbacks on?